# What should be the content of the first sector in a UEFI system with GPT partitions?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, uefi, gpt, efi

As i understand, in UEFI machines there is no MBR/VBR code, and the UEFI firmware directly gives control to the OS boot loader (.efi file).

My question is, what should be first sector of such system contain? Is there any standard?

Because when i check the first sector on some Windows 10 virtual machines in VMware, even tho the virtual machine is configured as a UEFI with GPT, the first sector is still the MBR code (that has the `invalid partition table` string at the end and starts with 0x33). And the second sector starts with `EFI PART`, which i assume is related to UEFI.

So my questions are:

1. What should the first sector contain in a UEFI machine? What about the second sector? Is there any standard?
2. What's the deal with the MBR code at the first sector in some UEFI machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, what should be first sector of such system contain? Is there any standard?

It's documented in the **[UEFI specification](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_8_final.pdf#page=184)**, as part of the overall GPT layout description.

According to section 5.2, the first sector (LBA 0) still has the same general structure as on non-GPT disks: 440 bytes for the BIOS boot code and 72 bytes for the partition table.

- UEFI systems indeed do not use the BIOS boot code that's in the MBR, so it may be zeroed out on pure UEFI systems – but it *may* have an actual bootloader instead, making the disk BIOS-bootable as well. (For example, GRUB2 and Syslinux will work on GPT disks in BIOS mode.)

  Many UEFI system disks will have some leftover BIOS boot code, as it often does not get erased if the OS gets reinstalled.
- GPT disks do not use the partition table that's in the MBR, but it must still be present – it needs to contain a "protective" partition which covers the entire disk and prevents old GPT-unware tools from treating the disk as unpartitioned (which could easily run to accidental data loss).

(Note that UEFI boot doesn't inherently require GPT partitioning – the same "EFI System Partition" holding .efi files can be created on a pure MBR-partitioned disk as well. That's an unusual combination for system disks though, and the specification only officially describes it for removable disks such as USB sticks.)

> And the second sector starts with EFI PART, which i assume is related to UEFI.

The second sector (LBA 1) **is where the GPT partition table starts**. The first 8 bytes of the GPT are just a "magic number" indicating that this is indeed the GPT (and not e.g. part of GRUB or some junk left over by that licensing system).

From section 5.3.2: "`Signature`: Identifies EFI-compatible partition table header. This value must contain the ASCII string “EFI PART”, encoded as the 64-bit constant 0x5452415020494645."

Comment: So to sum up the first question, the first sector could be zeroed out, or could be MBR code, based on the decision of the UEFI vendor, and overall it doesn't matter whether it has MBR or nothing, as it never gets used, right?

Comment: Because my main concern is, when i see a UEFI based system that has an empty first sector, is that normal?

Comment: Not exactly – the _boot code_ area of the MBR sector can be zeroed out, but the _partition table_ area should not be. GPT disks with a completely empty LBA0 will still work, but it's not exactly compliant with the spec (which says LBA0 needs to have either a full legacy MBR _or_ a protective MBR, no third option).

Comment: Who makes the decision on these and implement them tho? Is it up to the UEFI vendor to have the first sector contain MBR code / partition table / empty, or up to the OS developers?

Comment: The firmware never writes those sectors (it does very little writing to the disk in general), usually it's either the OS installer and/or various partitioning tools (fdisk, GParted, etc) that decide how to initialize an empty disk. See e.g. the [Linux `fdisk` source](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/libfdisk/src/gpt.c#L2667-L2744) or [FreeBSD `gpart`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/sys/geom/part/g_part_gpt.c#L682-L716). Some disks come pre-partitioned from the factory, where the manufacturer might have written their own tools.